# Creating dropdown submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi There can anyone help me i try to create a dropdown submenu but it doesn't work for me.

I dont know how to reate a nice menu.
example:
When i hover over "massages" then the menu must come down and show the submenu.

css here

```css
.menu{
width:821px;
height:42px;
margin:0px;
background:url(images/menu.gif) no-repeat left;
}
.menu ul{
list-style:none;
padding:0 0 0 15px;
margin:0px;
}
.menu ul li{
display:inline;
}
.menu ul li ul{
display:inline;
}
.menu ul li a{
float:left;
height:42px;
border:none;
padding:0 15px 0 15px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
line-height:42px;
font-size:14px;
}
.menu ul li.aktivni-active a{
float:left;
height:42px;
border:none;
padding:0 15px 0 15px;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:42px;
font-size:14px;
```

Html:

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>                                                                         
    <li class="aktivni-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="massages.html">Massages</a></li>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="aanbiedingen.html">Aanbiedingen</a></li>
   </ul> 
     <li><a href="aanbiedingen.html">Aanbiedingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="prijzen.html">Prijzen</a></li>
       <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>

       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone explane me how to create a dorpdown submenu on "Massages"

Thnx

Comment: you have to use either` jquery` or other library to get drop-down-effect on hover. or better use bootstrap framework to make it quick.

Comment: oke i dont know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kruxor/cRqhP/2/light/)

```
    /* Menu Dropdown */
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
 ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
 ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
 ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
}
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu a {
    width:150px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
/* Top Nav Background Hover */
 ul#menu li a:hover {
    background:#000;
}
ul#menu li ul li a:hover {
    background:#999;
}
/* 3rd level nav */
 ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 115px;
    width: 100px;
}
/* show the 3rd level when the second is hover */
 ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
/* Menu Dropdown */
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your markup, as far as I know submenu should be part of list item it refers to

```
<ul>
<li class="simple-item">item</li>
<li class="submenu">item
    <ul class="submenu-goes-inside-li">
        <li class="simple-item">item</li>
        <li class="simple-item">item</li>
        <li class="simple-item">item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul
```

In your case submenu is separated from list items.

Comment: Oke and when i have done that i can go to the css and change the look.

Comment: the idea is that submenu will be allways hidden "display: none"
and when you :hover over li which hold submenu you should change display of submenu to block;
.menu li :hover ul {
   display: block;
}
should be all

Comment: i have a big question how do you see it when you use my code that i have already.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same structure you have just add class to the drop menu,

set ul inside the dropMenu to display none, then to display on however. You can use css3 or jquery to make it have a nice animation or toggle.

`<div class="menu">`
`<ul>`
    `<li class="aktivni-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>`
    `<li class="dropMenu"><a href="massages.html">Massages</a></li>`
            `<ul>`
                `<li><a href="aanbiedingen.html">Aanbiedingen</a></li>`
            `</ul>` 
    `<li><a href="aanbiedingen.html">Aanbiedingen</a></li>`
    `<li><a href="prijzen.html">Prijzen</a></li>`
    `<li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>`
    `<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>`

`</ul>`
`</div>`

CSS

.menu ul{
  display:none
}
.menu:hover ul{
  display:block;
}

if you want some better just use jquery http://api.jquery.com/toggle/